# Why using Angular Moment returns all january in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-moment

I am using

```
<div ng-repeat="usage in previousUsage" 
     <p>{{usage.Month | amDateFormat : 'MMMM' }}</p>
</div>
```

usage.Month data are numbers 1-12 
The data returns January

Comment: `amDateFormat` probably expects timestamp... so it is formatting 1 to 12 milliseconds after 1970-01-01 => January.

Answer (score 1):

`amDateFormat` expects to get a date as its value. Not necessarily a timestamp, but any kind of object that `moment.js` will be able to create a `moment` object from (`Date` object, string, timestamp in milliseconds, etc.).

When you use a number between 1-12 as your input, moment will see it (as @pavel-horal commented) as the amount of milliseconds that had passed since the beginning of 1970-01-01. Then you use the filter to display the month, and you'll get January.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I just did

```
 <div ng-repeat="usage in previousUsage" 
      <p>{{dateFilter(usage.Month) | amDateFormat : 'MMMM' }}</p>
 </div>

 $scope.dateFilter = function(month) {
      var objDate = new Date(month);
      return objDate;
 };
```

Something along these lines - it returned back as January, February, March, etc...